# Как исправить ошибку добавления? Подсветка поля?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Разобрался с капчой, проверяется при неверном вводе, но!!!

1. Когда я не правильно ввожу символы - форма обновляется. Как пофиксить?
2. Когда я ввожу правильно все, то как добавить данные в бд ? На данный момент через `ajax` просто пишет пустоту(типа успех).
3. Как выделить поле красной рамкой, если пустое, а не писать алерт? И нужно подсветить то поле какое пустое.

Файл check_capcha.php

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION["code"] == $_POST["captcha"]) {
    if (isset($_POST["send"])) {
    $name     = $_POST['com_name'];
    $email    = $_POST['com_email']; 
   $query = 'INSERT INTO comments (name, email) VALUES (:name, :email)';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array( ':name'=>$name, ':email'=>$email));    
  }
}   
else { 
    die("Wrong TEXT Entered");
}
```

Файл js

```
$('#send_com').click(function() {

    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#mail').val();
    var captcha = $("#captcha").val();

      if (name == '' || mail == '' || captcha == '')
        {
          alert("Fill All Fields");
          return false;
        }
        else
        { 
          var dataString = 'captcha=' + captcha;
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "check_captcha.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(html) {
        alert(html);
        }
        });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Возможно что бы формы у тебя не уходила стоить тебе добавить event.preventDefault() в твоем обработчике.

Comment: мне надо, чтобы при неверных символах(капче) форма не уходила, а щас она уходит.... мне это не нужно.
Или подскажи как сделать

Comment: Ну повесить событие на нажатие кнопки в ней event.preventDefault() что бы форма не отправлялась, проверяем капчу если верно submit()

Comment: можно пример продемонстрировать?

Comment: Если верно понял то примерно так [http://pastebin.com/mp27gDcm](http://pastebin.com/mp27gDcm)

Comment: но как совместить с php и проверкой? Когда капча неверная - не отправлять ничего, а когда правильно - отправлять

Comment: Ты хочешь, что бы просто всю работу сделали за тебя?

Comment: Отдельный запрос отсылай тогда через ajax, но тогда странная капча у тебя будет... Посмотри готовые примеры. Капча должна проверяться после отправки ВСЕЙ формы на сервер, а не отдельно капча, отдельно форма.

Алгоритм такой должен быть. 1. Генерируем капчу и сохраняем в сессию. 2. Выводим форму с капчей 3. Отправляем форму 4. Проверяем капчу если верно добавляем в БД, если нет выводим форму с ошибкой и новой капчей (php).

Comment: так нормального примера не могу найти с применением добавления комментариев и проверки сессии..

Comment: [http://www.myfirstsite.ru/articles/captcha-with-php-2](http://www.myfirstsite.ru/articles/captcha-with-php-2)